# HTML redirect to page for button

Tags: html

How do I make it that so when a person clicks on a button it will take them to a page, currently I have (This is HTML by the way):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="Contact.html">Get in touch</button>
```

Comment: Change the button to `<a>`

Comment: Use an anchor (`<a>`), not a button!

Answer (score 0):

Use "onclick"

JS location.replace will redirect you to a page of your choice.

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.replace('http://www.google.com')" class="btn btn-success" href="Contact.html">Get in touch</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="Contact.html"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >Get in touch</button> </a>
```